# Please help identify the LEGO set from picture

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Got this from a bulk partly assembled.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [Darth Vader Transformation (7251)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7251-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]